# A polymorphic addition function in SML without using datatype

Tags: polymorphism, sml, type-conversion, abstract-data-type

I've made some progress in my learning of SML, trying to solidify my understanding of some of the most basic concepts. The following exercise proves that there is still much to be learned.

I'm asked to implement a function named add that receives two numbers and returns their sum. Problem is, add is supposed to receive a disjoint union of integers and real numbers, and return a disjoint union in the following manner: if both numbers received are integers, it should return the sum as an integer. Otherwise, if one of both of the arguments is real, the sum should be returned as a real number.

The most reasonable solution is to use datatype, yet I'm specifically instructed not to use it in any way, shape or form. To put it in other words, I should implement some sort of mechanism for determining the type of the parameters, and, as it follows, determining the return type.

All attempts were futile. Either SML infers that my parameters are of one specific type (which is not the case), or it demands the return value to be of a certain type, which is quite understandable but still frustrating. I've no idea how to overcome SML's typing restrictions. If it is of any use, I'm hinted to use tuples.

Comment: The task is difficult exactly because it implies the use of datatype, but prohibits it. So no, there's no use of datatype or abstype. I haven't learned about opaque signatures, so it probably isn't needed as well. The goal is to use tuples instead of datatype.

Comment: I deleted that comment when I realized that the hint about tuples suggest a relatively low-tech solution as outline by my answer below. If that isn't what your instructor has in mind than I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd really recommend reviewing the answer submitted by John Coleman, as this is the most reasonable way to approach it. However, my instructor had something different in mind. So for the sake of future generations, here's my primitive and utterly impractical implementation, which is what was expected:

```
fun add (a, b, _, _, 0) = (a+b, 0.0)
  | add (_, b, x, _, 1) = (0, real(b) + x)
  | add (_, _, x, y, _) = (0, x + y);
```

There is quite a resemblance to the C union data type. A tuple of 5 elements is used to send arguments to the function: 2 integer entries, 2 real entries and a tag which differentiates between the 3 possible ways of adding them (int/int, int/real, real/real). Again, this was written for educational purposes only, so for any practical use of this function please refer to John Coleman's answer.

Comment: Okay, but it seems to clash with the original description of the problem ("to implement a function named add that receives two numbers and returns their sum"). If the return type is `int*real` then you are using `int*real` for the disjoint union, so it would make sense to define a function which receives two such tuples. But then  `add ((2,0.0), (0, 0.0))`  is ambiguous between `(2, 0.0)` and `(0, 2.0)` - hence the 5th element which has the effect of making the sum not a function of its terms alone. Maybe it would be more principled to use `int*real*bool` as the type of both input and output.

Answer (score 4):

I find the question a bit odd since in SML the phrase "disjoint union" usually *means* a tagged union defined by a `datatype` declaration. The hint about using tuples got me to thinking about ... options. There is a natural way to think about the disjoint union of `int` and `real` as a *subtype* of `int option * real option` whereby e.g. `5` corresponds to `(SOME 5, NONE)` and `5.0` corresponds to `(NONE, SOME 5.0)`. I know of no way on the level of types to enforce the implied restriction that the only valid patterns involve one `SOME` and one `NONE` but you could define your functions so that they crash if you try to use them with `(NONE,NONE)` or `(SOME n, SOME r)` patterns -- either by not supplying definitions for those patterns or by explicitly raising an error. This will prevent your functions from being used on anything other than values that can be interpreted as lying in the union type.

Using this, it is relatively easy to define a function `add` so that e.g.

```
add (SOME 1, NONE) (SOME 5, NONE)
```

evaluates to `(SOME 6, NONE)`. Since this is an assignment I don't want to say anything more.

I am not completely sure that this is the sort of thing that your instructor has in mind, though it does seem like a reasonable interpretation.

Comment: Sadly, we haven't learned SOME and NONE as well... Nevertheless, it was enlightening, thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: @JeanFrancoisClout Odd. It is manifestly impossible to write a function `add` with both `add(1,1) = 2` and `add(1.0,1.0) = 2.0`. You could try to represent things as `int*real` in a way which is *almost* like my suggestion - but then `(1,1.0)` is ambiguous. You could do something like `int*string*real` with the string component acting like a type tag -- but that is borderline silly.

Comment: *'a option* is a datatype, too. Since Standard ML does not support disjoint unions without datatypes, and does not support custom function overloading, one could hack the compiler into provide a `+` operator that also overloads to `int * real -> real` and `real * int -> real`. Since that is outside the scope of *writing a function in Standard ML*, the exercise seems pretty futile to me.

Comment: @SimonShine Good point. I thought that perhaps OP's instructor was simply stipulating that a solution without an explicit use of  the `datatype` keyword would be enough. It really is hard to make sense of the question. I suspect that the instructor was thinking about using `int*real` -- but that can't be used in any straightforward way to provide a *disjoint* representation.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I wasn't the only student confused by his description of the task. I haven't submitted my assignment yet, but I'm pretty sure he meant something among the lines of the answer I submitted. He was expecting us to send the arguments to the function in a 5-entries tuple.